# My Postfix mail server receives login attempts from unknown users (brute force attempt) - what to do?

Tags: security, email, postfix, ssl, dovecot

I have a postfix + dovecot mail server, today while checking my logs I see login attempts from unknown users / ip adresses, I guess this has to be a brute force attack.

How could I stop and eventually prevent this?
Help would be much appreciated!

log:

```
Aug 24 15:36:34 mail dovecot: auth: passwd-file(zamudio,201.222.55.26): unknown user (SHA1 of given password: f72ac0)
Aug 24 15:36:36 mail postfix/smtpd[12568]: warning: unknown[201.222.55.26]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Aug 24 15:36:36 mail postfix/smtpd[12568]: disconnect from unknown[201.222.55.26] helo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Aug 24 15:38:38 mail postfix/anvil[12413]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:200.124.242.82) at Aug 24 15:30:49
Aug 24 15:38:38 mail postfix/anvil[12413]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:200.124.242.82) at Aug 24 15:30:49
Aug 24 15:38:38 mail postfix/anvil[12413]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Aug 24 15:30:49
Aug 24 15:39:34 mail postfix/smtpd[12571]: connect from unknown[190.117.185.251]
Aug 24 15:39:35 mail dovecot: auth: passwd-file(helene,190.117.185.251): unknown user (SHA1 of given password: cb4a0f)
Aug 24 15:39:37 mail postfix/smtpd[12571]: warning: unknown[190.117.185.251]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Aug 24 15:39:37 mail postfix/smtpd[12571]: disconnect from unknown[190.117.185.251] helo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
Aug 24 15:42:17 mail postfix/smtpd[12574]: connect from unknown[175.140.139.233]
Aug 24 15:42:18 mail dovecot: auth: passwd-file(payroll,175.140.139.233): unknown user (SHA1 of given password: 4de472)
Aug 24 15:42:20 mail postfix/smtpd[12574]: warning: unknown[175.140.139.233]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Aug 24 15:42:20 mail postfix/smtpd[12574]: disconnect from unknown[175.140.139.233] helo=1 auth=0/1 quit=1 commands=2/3
```

Comment: Personally, I use `fail2ban`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I check fail2ban out. I am wondering, how my server got discovered by attackers so fast while its more in a development stage, started only about 10 days!?

Comment: @EdmondTamas Not strange, there are whole server farms just constantly scanning whole IP blocks for open ports.

Comment: @Kusalananda, this is kinda sad, I guess this is how things work lately on the web. Shi**. :(

Comment: "Lately"? It's been going on for years :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is trying to use as open relay. You need define [smtpd_relay_restrictions](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_relay_restrictions) option. By default it use rules:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,
                           permit_sasl_authenticated, 
                           defer_unauth_destination
```

Which means that open relay is closed.

As your server is public, you need to humility with the constant attempts from internet bots to send mail through your server.

- Use complex passwords
- take care about Postfix security ([Postfix SASL](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html), [Postfix TLS Support](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html))

Or you can block other ips and allow only trusted ips/networks if your server works only as testing environment

Comment: Is there not a "fail2ban" or something similar for SMTP brute force attacks?